# Write data if it matches a criterion

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas

I have a datafile with 3000+ variables in it. Each row contains the data from one individual. Not all individuals have data for each variable. In other words the data file looks something like the following:

```
V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6
ID1, ,  , 4, 2, 
ID2,1, 2,  ,  ,  
ID3,1,  ,  ,  , 3
```

What I would like to do for each row (i.e., for each individual) is to put that row's data into its own .csv file. The catch is that I only want the variables for which that person has a value, though. So ID1's .csv file would look like:

```
V1,V4,V5
ID1,4, 2
```

I tried beginning with the following, but was getting stuck on exactly how to proceed:

```
df_datafile = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df_datafile2 = df_datafile.fillna(0)
for row in df_datafile2.itertuples():
    index,V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6 = row
    file = open("%s.txt" % (V1),"w")
    for column in df_datafile:
        if column != 0:
            file.write("%s" % (column))
```

All this code did, however, was give me all the variable names in a .csv filed named after V1.

Comment: so where you have missing values are they appearing as `NaN` in the df? you could do `df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().to_csv(str(x['V1']) + '.txt'), axis=1)`

Comment: I suggest not using `file` for your `open()` object. `file('name')` returns a file object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
df_datafile = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
for row, data in df_datafile.iterrows():
    data.dropna().to_frame().transpose().to_csv('file_{}.csv'.format(row))
```

You could probably skip the `fillna()` step if you later drop the `0` values again (that's why it doesn't say `df_datafile2`).

Comment: This completely fails to address the OP's requirement of not writing columns with no values, won't this just write out all cols with missing values replaced with `0`?

Comment: That is so close to what I'm looking for. Just three more things: 1) how do I completely drop the variables that have no values for that participant? All of the variables are being written to the new file; 2) the .to_csv() transposes the variables so they are now in a column rather than in a row. Is the best solution to just use .transpose() before writing the file? 3) how do I write the V1 variable as the name of each individual .csv file?

Regarding EdChum's comment, the output of the variables with no values is blank/null (i.e., not with 0s).

Comment: For `.dropna()` to be effective, the values need to be `np.nan`. You can specify `na_values` as  `.read_csv()` parameter if your missing values appear with some value other than `np.nan`. Once your missing values are `np.nan`, `dropna()` will get rid of all of them.http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html

Comment: To write horizontally, `.transpose()` is probably the best way - see updated answer.